# What math have I missed as an Engineeering graduate?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, education

To explain, I have a Master's in Engineering from a well known university. We did a wide variety of mathematical topics, vector calc, perturbation methods, numerical methods, linear algebra, discrete maths, etc, etc. Basically a whole load of math and stats classes (econ was part of the course too). Now I work in finance where I've come across stochastic calculus and a lot of computation related stuff.

And yet I often come across wide fields of mathematics that I've never even heard of. Naturally this is to be expected, since I didn't do a math degree. It was a close call after high school what I was going to study. I was quite into math contests, though I figured formal study at uni would be quite different from solving short trick questions.

Is there a consensus as to what the major areas are? Where will I find the most new and interesting maths given my background?

I realise there's a degree of subjctivity involved.

Comment: Uhm, well, I would say: different discipline needs different mathematics. Don't you think that Finance is _a bit_ different from Engineering?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_mathematics_topics

Comment: The traditional four pieces were analysis, geometry/topology, algebra, logic/foundations. Your classes have all stayed in or near the analysis part, and you have not mentioned PDE or measure theory. I do not think this represents a current consensus on major areas, it was at one time.

Comment: An example. As an engineer, I've never learned the principles of Linear Programming. But had to learn that in a rush in order to be able to teach some basic LP to Economy students.

Comment: I think it is safe to say that this question is either *too broad* or primarily based on opinion. Given that an average math PhD is still missing at least 95% of known math (I think I'm flattering myself and a few others with that estimate), it is safe to say that you have missed nearly all. But you aren't alone in that!

Comment: As someone who trained as engineer and then as a mathematician, the depths of engineering mathematics is not great. I would argue that truly, you haven't even encountered calculus.

Comment: Here's someone's classification of top-level subjects:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_Subject_Classification#First-level_areas

Answer (score 2):

Some major areas in order of increasing relevance to your background, to the best of my knowledge: logic/foundations, abstract algebra, topology, geometry, analysis (and combinations of the previous).

There are also subsets of things you've seen that have likely been glossed over in the context in which you've been taught.  For example, in the realm of partial differential equations, you likely have not bothered with the existence/uniqueness theorems, or dealt with the subtle distinction in considering functions as distributions or within the weak topology, as opposed to the usual framework.  Within linear algebra, it is likely that you never discussed vector spaces that weren't either $\Bbb R^n$ or $\Bbb C^n$, though many more useful vector spaces exist.  Infinite-dimensional vector spaces are mostly the subject of functional analysis, and "vector spaces" over finite-fields or rings tend to fall under the purview of the "algebraic" areas.

In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if you've already dealt with quite a bit of analysis, if only in passing. It plays a key role in the foundations of both numerical methods and perturbation theory.  Measure theory, which I would consider a subset of analysis, is particularly important, not least in anything to do with probability.

There's a lot of interesting math out there, it's hard to say what might be the most interesting for you.  There are some things you've seen that are deeper than you might imagine, and there are whole worlds you've probably never been introduced to.  Personally, I think Lie algebraic structures are pretty neat.